# Merge two or more base64 code in one PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, merge, base64

I have two or more variables that have base64 values which are PDFs.
Is there anyway that I can merge all my variables and they become one PDF, beacause it is impossible to download more than 1 PDF via HTTP.

I will be really thankfull for your answers.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you can't do with the base64 data. you'll have to decode back to a pdf file, use your pdf library of choice to append one doc into the other, then re-encode to base64. How to do that? That's up to you to figure out. We're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: The catch is there that I don't want to keep them in base64. My SOAP server gives me back several base64 codes that I keep in different variables and I want to download them as one PDF.

Comment: Irrelevant. doesn't matter how/where you get the pdfs from. if you want to download a single one, you'll have to write some code to merge them.

Comment: You really thought that I didn't try ? I have been googling all day long, but I can't find an answer for PHP.....

Comment: http://php.net/base64_decode. and there's LOTS of pdf libraries for php.

Comment: I have already read that documentation and I didn't seem to find how to merge two or more base64 codes into one PDF... If I knew the answer I would never come to spam stackoverflow. And why are you even answering me if you don't want to help me.....

Comment: And like I said. you **CANNOT** do **ANYTHING** with the base64 data. you decode those strings into actual pdf data, feed that pdf data to your pdf library of choice, MERGE the two pdfs to produce a NEW pdf, then encode that NEW pdf into base64 again

Answer (score 0):

Old question but my solution.
I found and use http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script94.php

get base64 data from DB and create temp files, save names in one array.

```
$pdf = fopen ('../tmp/test'.$rowp['id'].'.pdf','w');
fwrite ($pdf,base64_decode($rowp['pdf']));
fclose ($pdf);
array_push($pdfs,'../tmp/test'.$rowp['id'].'.pdf');
```

then for names in the array

```
$merge->add($pdfs[$i]); //add next file
unlink($pdfs[$i]); //clear temp one
```

finally output to the browser

```
$merge->output();
```

Comment: Where does the `$merge` object come from? Edit: Nevermind, it was from the FPDF library.